# Поиск строк в датафрейме, данные которых предоставлены в виде процентов в столбце ratings, и замена значений этих строк в столбце ratings на float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм `data` с данными минкультуры о кинопрокате за какой-то промежуток времени. В таблице есть столбец `ratings`, в нём хранятся рейтинги фильмов (данные взяты с кинопоиска) в виде вещественного числа с округлением до одного знака после запятой, например 9.4. Однако так же встречаются рейтинги в процентах (на кинопоиске это рейтинги ожидания, какой-то объективной оценки они не несут), например 67%. Изначально столбец имеет тип данных `object`, но его нужно привести к вещественному типу данных. Конечно можно воспользоваться `pd.to_numeric(data['ratings'], errors='coerce')` и просто проигнорировать все, что с ходу не переводится, но хотелось бы воспользоваться более аккуратным способом.

Я хочу отыскать все строки, которые имеют значения в процентах в столбце ratings и привести их к вещественному типу, например 59% -> 5.9. Я пытался отыскать такие строки с помощью цикла `for` и конструкции `try-except` следующим образом:

```py
for i in range(len(data.index)):
    try:
       data.loc[i, 'ratings'] = data.loc[i, 'ratings'].astype('float64')
    except: 
        print(f'Индекс: {i}')
```

Идея в том, что строки, которые не переводятся в вещественный формат в столбце `ratings`, должны выдавать свой индекс, но почему-то печатаются просто все индексы по порядку.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать мою задумку? Можно ли реализовать решение данной проблемы вообще без циклов (насколько я знаю при работе с Pandas стоит искать альтернативу циклам)? И как вы думаете, стоит ли серьезно запариваться по этому поводу или просто воспользоваться методом `pd.to_numeric(data['ratings'], errors='coerce')`, если им воспользоваться, то получится всего 29 пропусков (помимо изначально пропущенных значений, которых 966), к тому же рейтинги в процентах не несут какой-то прям объективной оценки фильма.

Comment: _Есть датафрейм data с данными_, подскажите, пожалуйста, у ккого он есть, или где его можно найти?

Comment: Что-то вы намудрили в вопросе. У вас что, в одном столбце могут встретится рейтинг типа 9.1  и строка (???) типа '59%'? Или у вас проценты заданы числом, например - 59? В первом случае, как такое может быть? А во втором -  как вы различаете, где рейтинг, а где процент -  ведь и рейтинг может быть задан числом (9), и процент -  дробью (51.7%)?

Comment: В одном столбце могу встретиться рейтинг типа 9.1 и строка '59%'

Comment: ссылка на data (https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Jnn79qaJKHpuAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем вам вообще цикл, если вы работаете с датафреймом и можно обрабатыавть данные векторно?

попробуйте так:

```
def cnv(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return float(s.strip("%"))/10

df['ratings'] = df['ratings'].apply(cnv)
```

теперь `df['ratings'].dtypes` будет

> dtype('float64')

И все. теперь у вас в рейтингах либо float с ректингом приведенным к одному виду, либо NaN

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Если в одном столбце и проценты и рейтинги, то как после преобразования всего в цифру вы будет разбирать, что такое -  например - 5.5 ?  Как вообще в одном столбце могуть быть разные по семантике данные?  То что их так представляет провайдер данных -  ну так он не думает о дальнейшей их обработке.

Поэтому вам надо СНАЧАЛА разделить данные, возможно перенести их в разные столбцы -  отдельно рейтинги, отдельно проценты, а уж потом думать об обработке.

Смешивать процентные данные, о которых всегда можно сказать, что объект с Х процентами в X/Y раз лучше, объекта с Y процентами,  с данными (рейтинговыми) о которых мы можем сказать только, что один лучше-хуже-равен другому и ничего больше -  это одна из главных ошибок, которые допускают неопытные статистики/датааналитики.  Это - азы науки о данных, первая лекция, которую многие просто пропускают, особенно те, кто торопиться начать программирование пропустив (ага - за ненадобностью) теорию. А получаемые в итоге результаты могут быть некорректными, а часто вообще безсмысленными.